# Redirect to both screen and pipe

Tags: bash

I want to pipe some output to another program and display a progress bar.

The code would look something like this:

```
echo "Progress:"
(for i in {1..10}; do echo $i; echo "." > screen; sleep 1; done) | xargs echo
```

where `screen` would direct it to the screen. This is not working because it will just write the dots to the file screen.

What I want to do is outputting the "." while the script is running and piping all the `echo "$i"` at once at the end, so only one piping occurs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to send the echo to the tty device. For example, echo 'somthing' > /dev/tty

But if you only want to show dots in the screen you don't need any redirection. Only echo '.'

Comment: How would I do `echo something > /dev/tty` and move around with `tput`?

Answer (score 2):

Try to use the /dev/stderr for writing stuff to the *screen*

E.g. something like this should do it.

```
echo "Progress:"
(for i in {1..10}; do echo $i; echo -n "." | tee /dev/stderr ; sleep 1; done)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [tee](http://ss64.com/bash/tee.html).

Answer (score 1):

If you just want a progress indicator, how about `pv`?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to copy to standard output and *files*, the `tee` command is your friend. If you want to pipe it to another command instead of a file, you could make the file `/dev/tty` (i.e., the screen), and pipe standard output to the other program.

Answer (score 1):

I like `pv` output. It's similar to how wget shows it's progress.

```
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ dd if=/dev/urandom bs=1M count=100 | pv | cat >/dev/null
  14MB 0:00:03 [4,84MB/s] [  <=>                                              ]
```

If you know the size of data to be transfered you can specify it `pv -s` it can even show estimates:

```
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ dd if=/dev/urandom bs=1M count=100 | pv -s 100M | cat >/dev/null
  14MB 0:00:03 [4,84MB/s] [===>                               ] 14% ETA 0:00:18
```