# redirect standard output to both screen and text file

Tags: batch-file, windows-server-2008, dos

I'm writing a dos batch script and one thing I want to do is to redirect a command line out to both standard output and a text file. I can do either, but not both. Also, I can't call it with another batch script or call it at command line.

the command I want to execute is `reg add "%regKey%" /f`
and the output is `The operation completed sucessfully.` and I want it to display on standard output and append in the text file.

So far, I have tried:

`reg add "%regKey%" /f>>%logfile%>CON` <-- only appended to textfile

`reg add "%regKey%" /f>CON>>%logfile%` <-- only displayed in standard output

I saw this [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7372993/redirect-to-both-screen-and-pipe), but it's for bash.

Comment: Is there really no `tee` command available on your platform?

Comment: @sarnold, unfortunately, `tee` is not available.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
reg add "%regKey%" /f>>%logfile%
type %logfile%
```

Which is easier to understand for yourself, and anyone else that will come along looking at your script.

Comment: it does display on screen and pipe the command output to text file. but it also display all the content in the text file. i think that'll scare the person running the script. also, i need to do that for multiple commands so the screen will get busy.

Comment: that'll work. i just need to do the `type` at the end. there is a pause,, but that's okay.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it.  Here is the magic, although the performance isn't that great and it wouldn't work for certain things:

```
@echo off
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
set logfile=test.out
echo. 2>%logfile% 
set /A count=0
set /A lastline=0
:loop
if not %count%==100 (
  set /A count += 1
  SET PR >> %logfile%
  CALL :printlog
  goto :loop
)
goto :pause
:printlog
SET incount=0
FOR /F "delims=" %%M in (%logfile%) DO (
    set /A incount +=1
    if %incount% GEQ %lastline% (
      ECHO %%M
      SET /A lastline=%incount%
    )
)
ECHO -
EXIT /B 0
:pause
pause
```